# Abbreviating lots of consecutive indexed summations

Tags: summation, notation, index-notation

I have lots of equations of the following form
$$\sum_{r_0}\sum_{r_1}\sum_{r_2}\cdots\sum_{r_N} x_{r_0} x_{r_1} x_{r_2}\cdots x_{r_N} $$
I can use the following notation for the product of $x$s
$$x_{r_0} x_{r_1} x_{r_2}\cdots x_{r_N}=\prod_{j=0}^{N} x_{r_j} $$
Is it also possible to shorten the summation notation $\sum_{r_0}\sum_{r_1}\sum_{r_2}\cdots\sum_{r_N}$?

Comment: Try $\sum\limits_{r_0,r_1,…,r_n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that.
For each $n+1$-tuple $r = (r_0, r_1, \ldots, r_n)$, let
$$x_r = \prod_{0 \leqslant i \leqslant n} x_{r_i} \text{ and }S = \sum_r x_r$$